# staleelementreferenceexception in Selenium Python on Nested Loops

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

recently I tried scraping, so this time i wanted to go from page to page until I get the final destination I want. Here's my code:

```
  sub_categories = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("ty-menu__submenu-link")                   
   for sub_category in sub_categories:
       sub_category = str(sub_category.get_attribute("href"))            
       if(sub_category is not 'http://www.lsbags.co.uk/all-bags/view-all-handbags-en/' and sub_category is not "None"):
          browser.get(sub_category)
          print("Entered: " + sub_category)


          product_titles = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("product-title")


          for product_title in product_titles:
              final_link = product_title.get_attribute("href")

              if(str(final_link) is not "None"):
                 browser.get(str(final_link))
                 print("Entered: " + str(final_link))
                 #DO STUFF
```

I already tried doing the `wait` and the `wrapper`(the try and exception one) solutions from here, but I do not get why its happening, I have an idea why this s happening, because it the `browser` gets lost right? when it finishes one item?

I don't know how should I express this idea. In  my mind I imagine it would be like this:

TIMELINE:

*PAGE 1 is within a loop, ALL THE URLS WITHIN IT IS PROCESSED ONE BY ONE

*The first url of PAGE 1 is caught. Thus do `browser.get` page turn to PAGE 2

*PAGE 2 has the final list of links I want to evaluate, so another loop here 
to get that url, and within that url `#DO STUFF`

*After `#DO STUFF` get to the second url of PAGE 2 and `#DO STUFF` again.

*Let's assume PAGE 2 has only two urls, so it finished looping, so it goes back to PAGE 1

*The second url of PAGE 1 is caught...

and so on... I think I have expressed my idea in some poitn of my code, I dont know what part is not working thus returning the exception.

Any help is appreciated, please help. Thanks!

Comment: Here is one idea. First iterate through all elements on one page and save all href data inside another list. Second iterate through list of saved   urls and do your stuff there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that after navigating to the next page but before reaching this page Selenium finds the elements where you are waiting for but this are the elements of the page where you are coming from, after loading the next page this elements are not connected to the Dom anymore but replaced by the ones of the new page but Selenium is going to interact with the elements of the former page wich are no longer attached to the Dom giving a StaleElement exception.

After you pressed on the link for the next page you have to wait till the next page is completly loaded before you start your loop again.

So you have to find something on your page, not being the elements you are going to interact with, that tells you that the next page is loaded.